How to update post content from acf fields using acf/save_post?
I am trying to update page content from acf fields attach to a page using acf/save_post action.
I noticed wp_update_post updates post_contet fields in DB but then overwrites it later. I tried remove action and adding action before and after respectively when updating content.
function update_page_content_after_acf_updated($post_id){
  $fields = get_fields($post_id);
  $description = '';


  if(get_post_type($post_id) == 'page'){
    if($fields['page_content']){
        foreach($fields['page_content'] as $content_block){

          if( in_array($content_block['acf_fc_layout'], ['intro-content', 'basic-content'])){
                    $description .= $content_block['content'] ? $content_block['content'] : '';
            }
        }
     }
  }

 $page = array(
    'ID'           => $post_id,
    'post_content' => $description,
 );

 wp_update_post($page);

}

add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_page_content_after_acf_updated');


https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/ $_POST will contain your new data.

@Snuffy is not about catch data. wp_update_post runs multiple times. So the post_content field updated and overwrite again.

You can avoid infinite save_post hooks call by removing hook into your callback, something like -
function update_page_content_after_acf_updated( $post_id ) {
    // Remove hook to avoid infinite loop.
    remove_action( 'acf/save_post', 'update_page_content_after_acf_updated', 99 );

    // DO YOUR CODING STUFF HERE.

    $description = ''; // Description goes here.

    // Update your page content.
    $page = array(
        'ID'           => $post_id,
        'post_content' => $description,
    );

    wp_update_post( $page );

    // Re hook it.
    add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'update_page_content_after_acf_updated', 99 );
}
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'update_page_content_after_acf_updated', 99 );


I thought it should work in this way after done some search. I tried with different priority like 20/50/60/99 but did not worked.
